# Excel formula- no coding

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of 800,000 merchant names and sales value at these merchant stores. There's another list of about 120 merchants. I have to look up for these 120 merchants in the first list and extract their sales figure. The challenge is that names have been spelt differently for some merchants, space has been used, or, only the first name has been spelt out. So for example. Walmart can have different spellings/formats- WALMART, Wal Mart, US Walmart, et al.
I am looking for a way to resolve this in excel. VBA could be a way out but I don't want to get into coding.

Comment: "I don't want to get into coding." - Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get into coding, this answer should probably be moved to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), but the simplest way to do this would be to use an Excel add-in called [Fuzzy Lookup](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011).

You should be able to find tutorials online for how to use it. While it may take some time to run (e.g. for 800K rows maybe a minute or so), the results will get you a lot closer to your end goal

Answer (score 0):

To do this with formulas you need an intermediary lookup list for each possible value.  Something that lists all the variations, and next to it has their cleaned up presentation value.  Then you can have subsequent structure lookip/pivot etc on this cleaned retreival.

An easy way to populate this intermediate list is to use a Pivot on Name to get all the uniques, then just assign a cleaned value to each one on a seperate tab that you use in the above.

Hope that helps